# Overriding an inline style with css

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanted to override an inline style that was set in a Wordpress CMS Editor. I'm aware that using `!important` would work but I wanted another pair of eyes on this and what is really happening.

```css
h2 span {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="color: #FFFFFF">Hello <span>World!</span></h2>
```

In the above, `#FFFFFF` was set from the editor. That's ok but any text wrapped in `span` must be yellow.

That should work but it does....not...ish. I use browser sync and once I made the change and save the file, the span becomes yellow. On refreshing the browser, `h2` no longer shows the yellow span. Any work around without JavaScript?

Comment: Try clearing your cache rather than refreshing

Comment: Just tried that but still the same.

Comment: Your code works as it is (the `!important` isn't needed either). Whatever the problem is, it isn't something you included in the question.

Comment: I would guess that it is an issue with your compiled style sheet. Does the line exist in there?

Comment: @SamWillis I dont fully understand, sorry.

Comment: can you show us the link of the page ?

Comment: Going to trying another computer and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @Sylar I've had issues before with browsersync getting ahead of itself when compiling sass. I usually fix this by resaving the files to cause another compile. You should open the compiled file and see if your `h2 span` styling exists in there, if it doesn't then the issue is with your compiling.

Comment: Strange, ive deleted my node_modules folder, ran npm install and all is well. I assume you may have a point there @SamWillis